# find a particular directory in working directory in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to check whether there exist directory named "name" in the current working directory. is it possible to do with ls?

```
   ls -l | grep ^-d
```

shows just directories but how to specify?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One should never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you are using bash, try this

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
fi
```

Comment: again the same error. 

`~> if [[-d "a"]]; then cd a; else echo "ER"; fi`
`-bash: [[-d: command not found`
`ER`

Comment: The spaces inside the [ ] are important. I.e. `[ -d "a" ]` will work but `[-d "a"]` will not.  Also, `test -d "a"` will work in bash and csh

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `-d` test is for.  Simply:

```
if [ -d "name" ]; then
    echo "yay!"
else
    echo "nay!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test -d 'name' && echo "It is there"
```

The `test -d 'name'` can be used in if statements and the like as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
ls -l | grep ^d name
```

Comment: That will search for 'd' at the beginning of a line in the file named 'name'.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert. But it worked for me? I don't mind learning a lesson if you have a second. this: ls -l | grep ^d Web
returned this: grep: Web: Is a directory       for me when I tried it out

Comment: There is nothing *wrong* with this approach except that you should never parse the output from ls [see link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls -l` display result using  long listing where the first field are the file-mode-bits. If it as folder the first character will be an `d` which is matched by the regex `^d`. So, this approach works but it is flawed (again, see link).

Comment: @FredrikPihl the `^d` part is fine, the problem is the number of arguments. This command passes two arguments to `grep`, triggering the `grep pattern file` behavior, so `grep` will not even read the output of `ls`; instead, it will try to read from the file `name`, causing a file-not-found error if it doesn't exist, simply not finding the pattern if `name` is indeed a folder, or normal search behavior on the file if it exists as a regular file.

Comment: well, you are right; I was too fast and didn't consider the `name`-part.